# .htacess is working into the home page but not working into the sub pages so, How to remove “web/app_dev.php” from Symfony2 URLs?

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I am new user in symfony please solve my issue 
I am writing the into the .htacess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Both are also work into the home page  but not in sub pages like

```
http://demo.co.uk/
```

but not this

```
http://demo.co.uk/app_dev.php/services
```

So how to remove 1app_dev.php1, I wanna just like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up the two environments.

- app_dev.php is your development version, it shouldn't be a requirement to remove it as you can see it only in development.
- app.php is your *default* environment, which is production. That should be the one which is hidden from the users.

Anyway, if you still want to do this, you have to replace the `RewriteRule` only. Try this `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```